# creates a tuple contains different drive class elements whose constructor received an int type, determined by its index in the tuple

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I have a base class whose constructor receives an int type named id, and several different derive class, with the same form of constructor as the base class.

Now I want to make a tuple that contains each of these elements,  with its constructor receives an id determined by its index in this tuple. Like what the following dumb function does:

```
class Base(){
    Base(int id){}
}

class Derive1, Derived2...Derivedn : public Base(){
     Derive(int id):Base(id){}
}

auto make_derives_tuple()->decltype(...){
   //manually write each elements' index in the tuple seems too ugly and unnecessary
   return std::make_tuple(Derive1(0),Derived2(1),Derived3(2)...); 
}
```

if the num of derived class is three:

```
struct Base{
    Base(int id){
        id_=id;
    }
    int id_;
};

struct Derive:public Base{
    Derive(int id):Base(id){

    }
};


struct Derive2:public Base{
    Derive2(int id):Base(id){

    }
};

auto make_derive_tuple()->decltype (std::make_tuple(Derive(0),Derive2(1),Derive3(2))){
    //I want the int passed to the derived class's construor automatically generated according to it's position in the tuple
    return std::make_tuple(Derive(0),Derive2(1),Derive3(2));
}
```

But manually write each elements's index in the tuple to pass to the constructor seems too ugly and unnecessary. Is there any elegant way of achieving this? Like using variadic template class or functions.

Comment: Could you provide actual example code even if that just contained two derived classes? The above sketch is not really clear because it doesn't adhere to C++ syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an elegant way to iterate over simply classes as `Derived1`, `Derived2`, `Derived3`, etc.

But is different if you can templatize your derive classes, adding a template index, as follows or in a similar way

```
template <std::size_t>
struct Derived : public Base
 { Derived (int id) : Base{id} {} };
```

If you can also use C++14, you can use `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
auto make_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple(Derived<Is+1u>{Is}...); }

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_derives_tuple ()
 { return make_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct Base
 { Base (int) {} };

template <std::size_t>
struct Derived : public Base
 { Derived (int id) : Base{id} {} };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
auto make_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple(Derived<Is+1u>{Is}...); }

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_derives_tuple ()
 { return make_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

int main()
 {
   auto t = make_derives_tuple<3u>();

   using T0 = decltype(t);
   using T1 = std::tuple<Derived<1u>, Derived<2u>, Derived<3u>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<T0, T1>::value, "!" );
 }
```

If you can't templatize (adding an index) the derived classes, the best I can imagine is pass the required derived classes as template variadic list to `make_derived_tuple()`.

The solution become

```
template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto make_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple(Ts{Is}...); }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto make_derives_tuple ()
 { return make_helper<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling example (where I've renamed `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` the derived classes

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct Base
 { Base (int) {} };

struct A : public Base
 { A (int id) : Base{id} {} };

struct B : public Base
 { B (int id) : Base{id} {} };

struct C : public Base
 { C (int id) : Base{id} {} };

struct D : public Base
 { D (int id) : Base{id} {} };

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto make_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple(Ts{Is}...); }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto make_derives_tuple ()
 { return make_helper<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}); }

int main()
 {
   auto t = make_derives_tuple<A, B, C, D>();

   using T0 = decltype(t);
   using T1 = std::tuple<A, B, C, D>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<T0, T1>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second one really helps, and I also learn from the first example.